# ConfigurationManager on Azure environment

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, configuration

I use this below code to read configuration. This code is used in global.asax Application_Start method.

```
        var showAllMethodSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowAllMethodsInSwaggerDocs"];
        bool showAllMethods;
        if (!bool.TryParse(showAllMethodSetting, out showAllMethods) || !showAllMethods)
        {
            ... code ...
        }
```

It works great in my local configuration (appSetting.config), but when I push my code to Azure. It not works.

Entry ShowAllMethodsInSwaggerDocs is visible in Azure panel with proper value (I add node in *.csdef and *.cscfg), but this value is not used. Why? Maybe should I use other class than ConfigurationManager?

Comment: Did you added the portal settings after app is deployed and are the app setting and  portal setting using the same name?

Comment: You might want to consider a library which abstracts this - https://github.com/aloneguid/config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the nuget package [Microsoft Azure Configuration Manager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/) to pick up the configuration settings both in the portal, and in your web.config.

Comment: @Jacek Yep, it definitely should! It's essentially a package that will read from the azure configuration and then fall back to the usual `*.config` files